# Initializing multiple variables on the same line

Tags: kotlin, variables

```
var etxtUserName: EditText? = null
var etxtContact:EditText? = null
var etxtPassword:EditText? = null
```

As you can see `etxtUserName`, `etxtContact` and `etxtPassword` is `EditText`. So, I want to add them in a line. Like we did in `Java`.

```
EditText etxtUserName,etxtContact,etxtPassword;
```

Is there any way to do same thing in `Kotlin`.

Here what I tried

```
var etxtUserName,etxtContact,etxtPassword: EditText? = null
```

error : `Property getter or setter expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use destructing declaration for this (works for up to 5 variables declaration, if you need more see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55891181/13968673):

```
inline fun <reified T> nulls() = List<T?>(5) { null }

var (etxtUserName, etxtContact, etxtPassword) = nulls<EditText?>()
```

Comment: This is working when I add it in `onCreate` method. But, it's not working when I added it as Global variable(above `onCreate`)..

Comment: What do you mean by global variable? There is no such concept in Kotlin.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip When I add any variable above `onCreate` that's known as global variable,isn't it? From whom I learnt it(`Java` for `Android`) he said....

Comment: If you are inside a class but outside of a method, it's a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html).

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Oh! Thanks... In `Java` all of them are `class`...i may be wrong also...

Comment: Yeah. But you're right. For classes, there is no way to avoid defining all the properties individually. It's a design decision to favour verbosity and over brevity for class definitions (so the class spec is explicit). But you can use [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html) to access the class properties later, especially for data classes.