# Deconstruct with List<Int> in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How does one deconstruct a List passed into a Kotlin function?

#### Problem:

Rather than passing a complex list of parameters to a function, I wanted to pass in a List and deconstruct it in the function body. The code below does not work, so I reverted to extracting each variable (Simplified code example below) - recommendations?

```
val (h1, m1, s1, h2, m2, s2) = timeData
```

#### Question:

What is the correct way to deconstruct the timeData into a component set of values?

#### Simplified Code Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner

const val HOURS = 3600
const val SECONDS = 60

fun secondsBetweenTwoMoments(timeData: List<Int>): Int {
    require(timeData.size == 6) { "List must have exactly 6 elements" }
    val h1 = timeData[0]
    val m1 = timeData[1]
    val s1 = timeData[2]
    val h2 = timeData[3]
    val m2 = timeData[4]
    val s2 = timeData[5]

    // Convert moment 1 and 2 to seconds
    val seconds1 = h1 * HOURS + m1 * SECONDS + s1
    val seconds2 = h2 * HOURS + m2 * SECONDS + s2
    return seconds2 - seconds1
}

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val inputs = mutableListOf<Int>()
    repeat(6) {
        inputs.add(scanner.nextInt())
    }
    val seconds = secondsBetweenTwoMoments(inputs)
    println(seconds)
}
```

to summarise, "Sir, I came across an interesting piece of magic..." (Chuckle)

Comment: Have you considered passing an object — e.g. an instance of a data class — instead of a list? That gives you type safety, property names (making the code easier to read, especially for the caller), and you may be able to use its properties directly without destructuring at all.

Comment: @gidds Thanks, the example above is purely to highlight the problem. I did as you rightly suggest consider passing an object. Alas the existing code base is a tad more complex than the example I provided and has rather a lot of constraints one being my time. Great point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have simply hit the limit of the number of destructuring operator functions the standard library has defined for a List. You can add one more, and then the destructuring code will work:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>.component6(): T = get(5)
```

As for why they only built in destructuring up to 5 elements, I think it's because beyond that it's getting to be a little bit fragile/unreadable to use and you might want to consider using a specialized data class instead of a List.

I'm not sure why you mention casting, since there is no casting occurring in your code.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I appreciate the clarification. I found a link to the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890980/kotlin-destructuring-more-than-five-components

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround / Solution

Based on @Tenfour04's answer (Thank you)... here are two potential approaches - posted for clarity.

Citations:

- [Kotlin destructuring more than five components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890980/kotlin-destructuring-more-than-five-components?noredirect=1&lq=1)

#### Example Code

```
import java.util.Scanner

const val HOURS = 3600
const val SECONDS = 60

operator fun <T> List<T>.component6() = this[5]
operator fun <T> List<T>.component7() = this[6]

fun secondsBetweenTwoMoments(timeData: List<Int>): Int {
    val (h1, m1, s1, h2, m2, s2) = timeData

    // Convert moment 1 and 2 to seconds
    val seconds1 = h1 * HOURS + m1 * SECONDS + s1
    val seconds2 = h2 * HOURS + m2 * SECONDS + s2
    return seconds2 - seconds1
}

fun secondsBetweenTwoMoments2(timeData1: List<Int>,
                              timeData2: List<Int> ): Int {
    val (h1, m1, s1) = timeData1
    val (h2, m2, s2) = timeData2

    // Convert moment 1 and 2 to seconds
    val seconds1 = h1 * HOURS + m1 * SECONDS + s1
    val seconds2 = h2 * HOURS + m2 * SECONDS + s2
    return seconds2 - seconds1
}

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val inputs = mutableListOf<Int>()
    repeat(6) {
        inputs.add(scanner.nextInt())
    }

    val seconds = secondsBetweenTwoMoments(inputs)
    println(seconds)

    val seconds2 = secondsBetweenTwoMoments2(inputs.subList(0,3),
                                             inputs.subList(3,6))
    println(seconds2)
}
```

Comment: You could also do `val (h1, m1, s1) = timeData.take(3)` and `val (h2, m2, s2) = timeData.drop(3)`.